# What exception should I raise for "operation is currently invalid"?

Tags: python, exception

Lets assume there is a method, and I want this method to be called only at certain conditions of a class variable, and otherwise I want to throw an exception:

```
 def foo(self):
   if not self.somecondition:
      raise ????
   else:
     #do the thing it supposed to do
```

Now I am looking for a correct exception for that. I went through them all at [python built-in Exceptions docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) and found nothing suitable. The classic `valueerror` is not quite suitable because there is not necessarily a problem with the values but rather with the method being called in this
circumstances.
What exception should I use then? Do I need to create my own in this case or does python has a built in answer?

Comment: It's up to you, but I would raise either a `RuntimeError` or a custom exception.

Comment: That purely depends on the context of the exception (which you did not describe).

Comment: @KlausD. what context haven't i described? What additional information do you need?

Comment: You have been keeping as generic as possible. What does this condition variable represent? For example if is represents something from the underlying OS it should raise an OSError or a subtype of it. If on the other hand your state is unique to your application you should define your own exception with an appropriate base class.